# Django NoReverseMatch Reverse for 'cart-add' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, url

I am getting the following error after I added `href="{% url 'cart-add' product.id %}"` to the add to cart button on my `product.html` file:

```
NoReverseMatch at /3/
Reverse for 'cart-add' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart\\/add\\/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

I believe that it's a urls pathing problem or settings, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. In case there are relevant files I missed displaying here, here is my github: https://github.com/sebapaik/django-shop

My product.html file looks like this:

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ object.imageurl }}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <h2>{{ object.brand }} {{ object.pname }}</h2>
          <p>${{ object.price }}</p>
          <p>{{ object.description }}</p>
**likely the problem below**
          <button class="btn" style="background:#f0c14b; border-color:#a88734;" href="{% url 'cart:cart-add' product.id %}">Add to cart</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endblock content %}
```

My Project/urls.py (main) looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('shop.urls')),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls')),
]
```

My shop/urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ProductListView, ProductDetailView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProductListView.as_view(), name = 'shop-index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name = 'shop-product'),
]
```

My cart/urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('add/<int:product_id>/', views.add_cart, name='cart-add'),
    path('', views.cart_detail, name='cart-detail'),
]
```

My settings.py looks like this:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '@9k!nb!1wi5*d=+*#3j+$gl%(#$z(c1aqsyh1p+qqs@)yeuh*_'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'shop.apps.ShopConfig',
    'cart.apps.CartConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

I am using Django 2.1.1, Python 3.6, and Windows 10

Comment: I'm guessing that you want to write `href="{% url 'cart:cart-add' object.id %}"` instead of <ss>`href="{% url 'cart:cart-add' product.id %}"`</ss>. I'm not sure that `product` is passed to the view or is it?

Answer (score 1):

Your `product.id` is empty according to the error message. You should use `object.id` instead in your template:

```
<button class="btn" style="background:#f0c14b; border-color:#a88734;" href="{% url 'cart:cart-add' object.id %}">Add to cart</button>
```

Comment: I get this error: `NoReverseMatch at /3/
'cart' is not a registered namespace`. I'm not sure why doesn't recognized the cart app. it's in the settings.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that Django recognise your request url is '/3/', what you want to reverse is 'car/add/3/', you could try simply use [href="/cart-add/{{product.id}}'"] to replace [href="{% url 'cart-add' product.id %}"].By the way, while your 'shop/urls.py' and 'cart/urls.py' has the same line "path('add//', views.add_cart, name='cart-add'),"? It may lead to some other problems.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I pasted the same urls.py file twice. I've tried what @blhsing suggested, but now I'm getting a namespace recognition error.